# c++ Pushing an object from one class into a vector in another class?

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm fairly new to c++ programming and was wondering if someone could solve this one issue for me?

I'm going to use some examples for my question here.

Let's say that in my main class I create a Bob object from the Blue class,

```
Blue Bob("bob", 3);
```

The Blue class takes a "name" and a size for the vector inside the class.

Now let's introduce another class, Red, which takes four parameters and has three objects,

```
Red GasPoweredStick("M000", "It never runs out of gas!", 1, 40);
Red Ozone("AFXE", "Filler", 4, 3);
Red Jupiter("KCAT", "Planets make terrible dinner guests", 99, 191919);
```

I want to add the Red objects to the vector in the Blue class under the Bob object, and then do things with those parameters,

```
Bob.addItem(GasPoweredStick);
Bob.addItem(Ozone);
Bob.addItem(Jupiter);
```

which leads to this "addItem" code,

```
void Blue::addItem(Red&)
{
    Items.push_back(Red());
}
```

I think my problem is at that above code...and the problem being that **the parameter information from the Red objects default to their constructor's values, making them all blank or 0.** instead of being filled with the information from the already created objects. The reason as to why I can't solve this myself but got this far is because this is an assignment that I am working on, but my current education with c++ has not mentioned this particular problem. The code is created from template or prior knowledge.

I don't have much experience with c++, but I'm guessing that the `addItem` function isn't taking in the three created objects but is instead copying the base `Red` class every time I asked it to push a new object.

I would appreciate any help! I hope I was clear enough. I'll try to clear things up if they need to be.

Comment: Your code may be less confusing if you didn't use caps for the first letter of a variable name, which is kinda unconventional. Look what the syntax highlighter did with it, for example!

Comment: I thought it was different for objects, thanks for the help. @Lightness Races in Orbit

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
Items.push_back(Red());
```

Your pushing back a newly created `Red` object using the default constructor. Just pass a reference:

```
void Blue::addItem(const Red& r)
{
    Items.push_back(r);
}
```

Comment: Since the `push_back` is going to copy the object anyway, you may as well accept a `const Red& r` so that you can give temporaries to `addItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Red should have a copying constructor and assignment operator:

```
void Red::Red(const Red& other)
{
(*this) = other;
}

Red& Red::operator=(const Red& other)
{
this->Name = other.Name; 
// TODO: copy other fileds
return (*this);
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear that this is required. Perhaps he's following the _rule of zero_ (which is _better_) or simply has no wrapped resources that require management. Certainly a missing copy ctor/op= is not the immediate cause of the stated problem.